# Android: Cannot add Button below Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to add a button just below gridview. It just not sure, p.s. this framelayout is inside another framelayout (base container). I have tried to set heigh=0dp and weight=1, but no luck. please help :) thx

Here is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/baseContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_recent_swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_recent_gridview"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recent_filterBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="my button"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color2"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_recent_swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:weight = "1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And remove the weight tag from the `GridView`